# Get all unique entries from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I think I'm on the right track.  I just don't know the sql command I need.

In this table I put a key, addend, category id.   I want to get one instance of all different addends.

so

> ```
>  1  10  3045
>  2  10  4055
>  3  20  4444
>  4  30  1111
>  5  30  7455
>  6  30  7000
>  7  41  8877
> ```

I would get an array filled with [10,20,30,41]

```
public ArrayList<String> getFinalCategorysCatIDsBasedOnAddend() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID_TABLE_4, KEY_BUTTON_TAG_ADDEND, KEY_CAT_ID };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_4, columns, KEY_BUTTON_TAG_ADDEND+" unique ", null,
            null, null, null);
    ArrayList<String> cat = new ArrayList<String>();
    int iSites = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CAT_ID);
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        cat.add(c.getString(iSites));
    }
    c.close();
    return cat;
}
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

***Solution***

Changed the query to

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_4, columns, KEY_BUTTON_TAG_ADDEND, null,
            KEY_BUTTON_TAG_ADDEND, null, null,null);
```

Comment: And when there are multiple category IDs for one addend, which one should be returned?

Comment: I don't need the category IDs just one instance of each addend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this [query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method you can set the first parameter to `true` to receive distinct results.

```
public Cursor query (
    boolean distinct, 
    String table, 
    String[] columns, 
    String selection, 
    String[] selectionArgs, 
    String groupBy, 
    String having, 
    String orderBy, 
    String limit
)
```

Comment: Thanks not sure how I missed it in the docs.  I also had to change the group by.